# jQuery click event doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm practicing doing a simple calculator using jQuery, I feel like the code is pretty simple in its own but no matter what I do absolutely nothing happens, as if there was no js file linked to beging with. Here's the jQuery code:

```
    function ud(n){
    $("#display").append += n;
}
function ans(c){
    c = eval($("#display").html);
    $("#display").append = c; 
}
function clc(){
    $("#display").append = '';
}

$("#button0").click(ud(0))
$("#button1").click(ud(1));
$("#button2").click(ud(2));
$("#button3").click(ud(3));
$("#button4").click(ud(4));
$("#button5").click(ud(5));
$("#button6").click(ud(6));
$("#button7").click(ud(7));
$("#button8").click(ud(8));
$("#button9").click(ud(9));

$("#addButton").click(ud('+'));
$("#subtractButton").click(ud('-'));
$("#multiplyButton").click(ud('*'));
$("#clearButton").click(clc());
$("#equalsButton").click(ans());
$("#divideButton").click(ud('/'));
```

and here is the html:

```
    <tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled></input></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><button id="button1" value="1">1</button></td>
  <td><button id="button2" value="2">2</button></td>
  <td><button id="button3" value="3">3</button></td>
  <td><button id="addButton">+</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button4" value="4">4</button></td>
  <td><button id="button5" value="5">5</button></td>
  <td><button id="button6" value="6">6</button></td>
  <td><button id="subtractButton">-</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="button7" value="7">7</button></td>
  <td><button id="button8" value="8">8</button></td>
  <td><button id="button9" value="9">9</button></td>
  <td><button id="multiplyButton">*</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
  <td><button id="button0" value="0">0</button></td>
  <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
  <td><button id="divideButton">&#247;</button></td>
</tr>
```

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? is there a much simpler way to do it? thank you in advance

Comment: `click()` expects a function but you are calling `ud()` instead which does not return a function. Will need to do `$("#button0").click(() => ud(0))` or `$("#button0").click(function(){ ud(0)})`

Comment: Also `append()` is a function. You are using it incorrectly. See the [`append()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: And check your browser dev tools console for errors (F12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify your code and refactor.
It should work.

In the original code contains some wrong syntax:

1. input filed should set value, so you should use `val()`, not use `append()`, and the usage of [append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is wrong in the code...
2. click event pass parameter, please see [jQuery click-eventData-handler](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler) and pass an execuded function is not expected.

```js
function ud(e) {
    var currentVal = $("#display").val();
    $("#display").val(currentVal + e.data.n);
}

function ans(c) {
 var result = eval($("#display").val());
 $("#display").val(result);
}

function clc() {
    $("#display").val('');
}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('#button' + i).click({n: i}, ud);
}

$("#addButton").click({n: '+'}, ud);
$("#subtractButton").click({n: '-'}, ud);
$("#multiplyButton").click({n: '*'}, ud);
$("#divideButton").click({n: '/'}, ud);
$("#clearButton").click(clc);
$("#equalsButton").click(ans);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input id="display" name="display" disabled></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="button1" value="1">1</button></td>
    <td><button id="button2" value="2">2</button></td>
    <td><button id="button3" value="3">3</button></td>
    <td><button id="addButton">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="button4" value="4">4</button></td>
    <td><button id="button5" value="5">5</button></td>
    <td><button id="button6" value="6">6</button></td>
    <td><button id="subtractButton">-</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="button7" value="7">7</button></td>
    <td><button id="button8" value="8">8</button></td>
    <td><button id="button9" value="9">9</button></td>
    <td><button id="multiplyButton">*</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button id="clearButton">C</button></td>
    <td><button id="button0" value="0">0</button></td>
    <td><button id="equalsButton">=</button></td>
    <td><button id="divideButton">&#247;</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll definitely have to sit down and read the documents. Your code worked even before you updated it except it was returning the double except for the number 9, but I changed it to 0 and its all good. And thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: hey, how can I make it to "reset" and show a single digit after I make an operation and click equal button?

Answer (score 1):

You are *calling* a function within the .click() event function, but it instead expects a function *reference* or an *anonymous function* as a parameter.

[$jQuery.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

[$jquery.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler)

1. Add a common className (e.g. 'numberKey') to your calculator buttons representing numbers.

   `<button type="button" class="numberKey" value="1">1</button>`
2. Select all of these buttons at once and use a single click event handler for all of them.

   ```
    $(function() {
        $('button.numberKey').click(updateDisplay);
    });

    function updateDisplay(clickEventObject) {

        // The button that was clicked can be referenced using
          // the 'this' keyword.

        // Variable-ize the button element into a jQuery object.
        let $button = $(this);

        // Get the 'value' attribute of the button
        let number = $button.attr('value');

        // Get the displayed value.
        var expression = $("#display").val();

        // Append the number to the display's value
        $("#display").val(`{$expression}{$number}`);
    }
   ```

---

FYI, the jQuery **.append** is not a property that can be appended to, or set to a value.  It's a function which can be passed a string value.  And that value will be appended to the contents of the selected element(s).

---

If you want to clear an input element, you should set its value to a blank string:

```
$('#display').val('');
```

---

The 'ans' (answer?) function can work like this:

```
function solve_ans() {
    let expression = $('#display').val();
    let solution = eval(expression);
    $('#display').val(solution);
}
```

---

Also, note that if you are using the same selector more than once in any context, it's usually worthwhile to cache/store the result of the selection in a variable and then reuse it, rather than re-selecting the same element(s).

```
function solve_ans() {
    // Referring to this $display variable avoids repeatedly re-selecting the same elements from the DOM whenever you may need to refer to them.
    let $display = $('#display');
    let expression = $display.val();
    let solution = eval(expression);
    $display.val(solution);

    $display.addClass('solution').removeClass('expression');
}
```

Good luck!